# How to convert Double to int directly?

Tags: java

May be this is silly question. I want to get rid of the fractional part of the **`Double`** number. But I cant do that. It shows the error that incompatible types. What to do?

`Double to int` conversion in one line....please help thanks

Comment: How about reading the documentation of the Double class? I am sure there is some method that will do the conversion.

Comment: You are talking about an error because of incompatible types. Then it's usually a good idea to show the code snippet you have tried. That helps giving better answers.

Comment: @Ingo i did googling and tried my best after that only I came to SO. Thanks for helping hands :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue()

Answer (score 184, accepted):

If you really should use Double instead of double you even can get the int Value of Double by calling:

```
Double d = new Double(1.23);
int i = d.intValue();
```

Else its already described by Peter Lawreys answer.

Comment: sorry guys. I tried google and found double to int only. So then I came to disturb our Friends here :) That works. many thanks

Comment: This is a *really* bad idea in loops. It's much better to work with primitives.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue()

Comment: why I did this and it gives me an error `double cannot be dereferenced`?

Comment: most likely you use a primitive type double and not Double, but you may want to ask that in your own question to provide more context.

Answer (score 27):

All other answer are correct, but remember that if you cast double to int you will loss decimal value.. so 2.9 double become 2 int.

You can use `Math.round(double)` function or simply do :

```
(int)(yourDoubleValue + 0.5d)
```

Comment: Also worth noting that 2.999999999999997 becomes 2, which is undesired in most cases.

Answer (score 24):

```
double myDb = 12.3;
int myInt = (int) myDb;
```

Result is: myInt = 12

Comment: Daneos the question was about converting `Double` to `int`. Not `double` to `int`.

Answer (score 11):

try casting the value

```
double d = 1.2345;
long l = (long) d;
```

Comment: no it was not double it is a `Double` number. Thats why it shows the error i think.

Answer (score 2):

```
int average_in_int = ( (Double) Math.ceil( sum/count ) ).intValue();
```

Comment: Math.ceil OR Math.floor is optional.