# Casting Double to Integer

Tags: java

I am running into a casting issue.  I cannot seem to figure out the problem since everything appears to be in order.  I understand that to explicitly cast from the Double wrapper class to the Integer wrapper class it can be done however, my compiler does not recognize it.  Am I missing something obvious?

The exact error I'm getting is : "Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'double' to 'java.lang.Integer'.

Thanks for your help!

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> shortestPath(String currentVertex, Set<String> visited) {
        double tempVal = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        String lowestVertex = "";

        Map<String, Integer> adjacentVertex = this.getAdjacentVertices(currentVertex);
        HashMap<String, Integer> lowestCost = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for(String adjacentNames : adjacentVertex.keySet()) {
            Integer vertexCost = adjacencyMap.get(currentVertex).get(adjacentNames);
            if(!visited.contains(adjacentNames) && (vertexCost < tempVal)) {
                lowestVertex = adjacentNames;
                tempVal = vertexCost;
            }
        }
        lowestCost.put(lowestVertex, (Integer)tempVal);

        return lowestCost; 
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Double to int directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404149/how-to-convert-double-to-int-directly)

Comment: @DavidBrossard no it is not. OP wants to Casting double to Integer

Comment: Why have `tempVal` declared as a double when it appears that you always want an int?

Comment: tempVal had to be declared as a double rather than an int because of the Positive_Infinity value.  All I had to do was change double tempVal to Double tempVal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cast directly from Double to Integer. You need to do the following:

```
Double d = new Double(1.23);
int i = d.intValue();
```

as suggested in [How to convert Double to int directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404149/how-to-convert-double-to-int-directly)

Comment: OP wants to Casting double to Integer

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera and what does the above code do?

Comment: OP want `Integer` not `int`

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera `Integer` and `int` autobox just fine, so where is the problem?

Comment: That segment of code is called by another function to find the shortest path for Dijkstras algorithm.

Comment: It would work, but it still creates an extra Double instance every time it's called (not speaking of the extra code :)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 lowestCost.put(lowestVertex, (Integer) new Double(tempVal).intValue());
```

Hope it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the easiest:

```
lowestCost.put(lowestVertex, (int) tempVal);
```

First, explicitely cast to an `int`, then have the compiler to autobox the `int` value to an `Integer`.

Note that this also eliminates the need to create various helper throwaway objects that other answers suggest (an extra `Double` or even a `String`). It is the most efficient way I can think of (at this moment).