# I converted double to int, but there is still an error, explain why?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, int, double

```
    int x1, x2; double d;
    d = (int)(Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c));
    if (d >= 0) {
        x1 = (-b + d) / 2*a;    // on this line
```

### "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int"

Comment: Maybe try casting d to an `Integer` instead of an `int`?

Comment: @Santiago:  That still wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not clear on why there are any integers involved in this code anyway.  The roots of a quadratic equation are not necessarily integers, so what exactly are you trying to accomplish by using integers and trying to convert to integers?

Answer (score 6):

Here `x1` shouldn't be an `int`.  It looks like you're using it to store a root of a quadratic equation, which of course is likely not to be a whole number.

Change `x1` (and probably `x2` too) to be a `double` and the problem will go away.

Incidentally, you want parentheses around `2 * a`, otherwise you're effectively putting `a` on the numerator, not the denominator.

Comment: Also the `(int)` cast needs to be removed when assigning to `d`.

Comment: @ajb Yes, that's true.  The `if` can also be removed, since `Math.sqrt()` always either returns something `>= 0`, or throws an exception.

Comment: @DavidWallace If the argument is negative, Math.sqrt returns a NaN, rather than throwing an exception. Whether it needs to be tested depends on what the code is supposed to do for an equation with no real solutions.

Comment: Oops, my bad.  I forgot about `NaN`.  Thanks @PatriciaShanahan.  Of course, the best thing for this code to do would be to check the sign of `b * b - 4 * a * c` before trying to square root it.

Answer (score 1):

`d` is a double, so `(-b + d)` is a double. Even if `b` isn't a double, it'll get widened to one for that expression. Therefore, `(-b + d) / 2*a` is a double. Java won't let you implicitly convert that double expression to an `int`, because you could lose precision.

Comment: I think the issue is that he thinks when he is type casting that he is actually changing the variable type instead of actually casting the value.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to do a cast to `int` at the point where you want to store the result of a `double` calculation into an `int`:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = 3.0;
    double c = 2.0;

    int x1, x2;
    double d;
    d = Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);
    if (d >= 0) {
      x1 = (int) ((-b + d) / 2 * a); // on this line
    }
  }
}
```

You should also take another look at where you are doing the sign test `d >= 0`. It will work, because the result of a `Math.sqrt` call is either a non-negative number or a NaN, but testing the square root operand before the call would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is from:

```
x1 = (-b + d) / 2*a;
```

Your variable  did still defined as a double.  When you add it to -b this will return a double.
Try saving this line as a new int variable instead of d:

```
 Int temp = (int)(Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c));
```

Answer (score 0):

`d` is still a double, because it was declared as a double. Casting only changes the type of a value; it won't change `d` itself to an `int`. If you want `d` to be an `int`, declare it as an `int`, like this:

```
int d;
```

instead of

```
double d;
```

and keep the rest of your code the same. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deadset on ending up with an int, you can do the following:

```
double answer = (-b + d) / 2*a;
x1 = new Double(answer).intValue();
```

Otherwise, the other answers have sufficiently told you why you're running into issues with casting.

[How to convert Double to int directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404149/how-to-convert-double-to-int-directly)

Comment: What is the advantage of boxing the `double` to a `Double` and using `intValue()`, as opposed to just casting to `(int)`?  Isn't that just redundant code to do the same thing?

Comment: @ajb, it is, just presenting an alternative.  If you want to get clever about it one could use Math.round() and then Long.intValue() as well.  They all get to the same end.