# Convert to double value to integer without rounding off

Tags: android, integer, double, rounding

I give view height according to percentage of screen. But views only get integer value. How can I convert integer values without rounding the numbers. I calculate according to the screen. As the double values turn integer values, the roundings are blank on the screen.

```
public class TutorialFragment extends BaseFragment {

private double mScreenHeight;

private double bgBlueHeight;

private double bgGrayHeight;

private double textHeight;

private double mPathHeight;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial, container, false);

    setTutorialPages();

    return mView;

}

private void setBackgroundGray() {

    ImageView bgGray = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.bg_gray_tutorial);

    bgGray.getLayoutParams().height = (int) bgGrayHeight;

    bgGray.requestLayout();

}

private void setBackgroundBlue() {

    ImageView bgBlue = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tutorial_dotted_blue_bg);

    bgBlue.getLayoutParams().height = (int) bgBlueHeight;

    bgBlue.requestLayout();

}

private void defaultScreen() {

    DefaultScreen.sharedInstance(getContext()).setDefaultScreen();

    mScreenHeight =  DefaultScreen.sharedInstance(getContext()).getScreenHeight();

    bgBlueHeight = mScreenHeight * 0.30;

    bgGrayHeight = mScreenHeight * 0.34;

    mPathHeight = mScreenHeight * 0.06;

    textHeight = mScreenHeight - bgBlueHeight - bgGrayHeight - mPathHeight;

}

    private void setText(String text) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_tutorial);

    textView.setText(text);

    textView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) textHeight;

    textView.requestLayout();

}

private void setTutorialPages(){

    defaultScreen();

    setBackgroundBlue();

    setBackgroundGray();

    setPath();

}

}
```

Comment: using `Math.floor`?

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404149/how-to-convert-double-to-int-directly

Comment: Here's a link that points to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468730/converting-double-to-integer-in-java