# What is type variable in java -(number)d

Tags: java, variables, numbers

I can't cast this value as `Integer` and I can't file what type is (I know is `String`) but I need convert as number, `Interger.parse()` does not work I get `Exception`.

```
String str = "-10d";
Interger.parse(str); //I get Exception
```

Comment: but what is this for a number: -10b????

Comment: Do you intend that "b" indicates that this is a binary number?

Comment: Sorry i make change i mean d.

Comment: @ChristosAntonopoulos that's a double, you should parse `Double.parse`

Comment: `d` stands for double;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do F and D mean at the end of numeric literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331200/what-do-f-and-d-mean-at-the-end-of-numeric-literals)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404149/how-to-convert-double-to-int-directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to convert your `String` to `int`.

```
String str = "-10d";
int i = Double.valueOf(str).intValue();
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`String str = "-10b"` (mentioned in question) or "-10d" (mentioned in title)?

If what you mean is -(number)d,then it is double.
try

```
double b = Double.parseDouble("-10d");
```

instead of using `Integer.parseInt`

Answer (score 1):

Here you get the `double` value:

```
String str = "-10d";
Double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
System.out.println(d);
```

And to get the integer value:

```
int intValue = d.intValue();
```

Other solutions, which change the input `string` for the `parse` method are (I don't recommend them):

```
int x = Integer.valueOf(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
int y = Integer.valueOf(str.replace('d', ' ').trim());
```

Comment: @Tom thanks for the hint, was not thinking about the results of this change

Answer (score 1):

You get Exception because it is not correct there are no `Interger.parse(str);` i think you want to make :

```
Integer.parseInt(str);
```

But your string have `d` and d work with Double not with Integer so instead use this :

```
String str = "-10d";
Double.parseDouble(str);
```